# Does a class inherit an abstract inner class declared within an interface when the class implements that interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, overriding, abstract

I am running the following java version
**openjdk version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)**

**Program 1**

```
class Outer{
abstract class Inner{
    void m1(){
        System.out.println("Inner class m1 method");
    }
  }

 }


class Outer2 extends Outer.Inner{
Outer2(){
new Outer().super();
  }
}
class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
new Outer2().m1();
 }
}
```

**input:** deep (master *) JavaStuffs $ javac sample.java
deep (master *) JavaStuffs $ java Test
**output:** Inner class m1 method

**Program 2**

```
interface Outer{
    abstract class Inner{
    void m1(){
        System.out.println("Inner class m1 method");
    }
  }
}
class J implements Outer{

}
class Outer2 extends J.Inner{

Outer2(){
    new J().super();
  }
}
class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Outer2().m1();

  }
}
```

**input:** deep (master *) JavaStuffs $ javac sample.java
**output:** sample.java:1309: error: illegal qualifier; Inner is not an inner class
        new J().super();
               ^
   1 error

**Program 3**

```
interface Outer{
abstract class Inner{
    void m1(){
        System.out.println("Inner class m1 method");
   }
 }
}
class J implements Outer{
class InnerJ extends Inner{

 }
}
class Outer2 extends J.Inner{
Outer2(){
new J().super();
 }
}
class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new J().new InnerJ().m1();
    new Outer2().m1();
 }
}
```

**input:** deep (master *) JavaStuffs $ javac sample.java
**output:** sample.java:1372: error: illegal qualifier; Inner is not an inner class
        new J().super();
               ^
   1 error

Here in **Program 2** and **Program 3** I expected that the class will inherit the inner abstract class when it implements the interface. But it's not happening so! Can anyone explain? A precise reason will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A member class defined inside an interface is always implicitly **`static`**. It's not an inner class, but a static member class, and it doesn't have an outer class instance associated with it.

The [Java Language Specification states this in section 9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.5):

> A member type declaration in an interface is implicitly public and
>   static. It is permitted to redundantly specify either or both of these
>   modifiers.

Hence, in your program 2, inside the constructor of class `Outer2`, you cannot say `new J().super();`, because `Outer2` doesn't have an outer instance - it is not an inner class. The error from javac says as much: "illegal qualifier; Inner is not an inner class"

Comment: it's not a class inside the interface, it's an abstract class. Your "automatic static class inside interface" doesn't apply here.

Comment: @DeepRoy It's a class inside an interface. That fact that it's abstract does it not make any less of a class. It's a static public abstract member class, *not* an inner class.

Comment: I think you are correct.  Even an abstract class inside an interface behaves as a static one.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Classes inherit instance variables and instance methods from their parents, and they implement the same interfaces.  They can access static members of their parent classes and directly or indirectly implemented interfaces *as if* they were inherited, but that's technically a different story.

Nested classes and interfaces are not inherited, neither from parent classes nor from implemented interfaces, but an instance of a child class can serve as the containing instance of its parent class's inner class.

Nesting a class or interface inside another provides first and foremost an additional level of namespacing.  `Parent.Inner` is a different class from `Child.Inner` -- without considering any other factor, you know because their names are different.  Child classes do not, therefore, inherit nested classes.  There's no good way to do it, and no particular advantage either.